# How to call style from constant file react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have a file `register.js` with some UI component.

```
import CustomHeader from '../components/Header';
...
 static navigationOptions = ({navigation, navigation: { state } }) => {
        return {
            title: '',
            headerStyle: CustomHeader
        }
    };
```

I try to create and call `CustomHeader` style from another constant file.

```
 import { getStatusBarHeight } from "react-native-safearea-height";
 import { Platform } from 'react-native'; 

 var iosMarginTop = getStatusBarHeight(true);
 const headerStyle = ({backgroundColor = '#000'}) => {
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    marginTop: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? iosMarginTop : 0
 }

 export default headerStyle;
```

How can i dynamically call `customHeader` style and pass some parameter for specific UI style for example `backgroundColor`? and by default, if none parameter passed, it will remain default value `"#000"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like this,

```
 const headerStyle = ({backgroundColor}) => {
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor ? backgroundColor : "#000",
    marginTop: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? iosMarginTop : 0
 }
```